# Google Analytics tracking 2 different contact form 7 in a singular page with DOM events

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7

I have 2 different contact form 7 in one page.

I want to tracking the single submission of the form because in Google Analytics i have 2 different conversion goal.

The code i've used is this:

```
<script>
 document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
 ga('send', 'event', 'Form contatto', 'submit', 'lead contatto diretto');
 }, false );
 document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
ga('send', 'event', 'Form contatto', 'submit', 'lead generation landing');
}, false );
</script>
```

But in analytics the goal being tracked doubles.

How i can specify for each form, the right event to send to GA?

Comment: How are your goals configured? Please share screenshots.

Comment: http://imgur.com/OBQWj8p
http://imgur.com/sMjucrP
in this way

Comment: Are you seeing the same goal converting twice? That shouldn't be possible as goals only convert once per session, but what you should be seeing is two goals converting on the same event, `wpcf7mailsent`. Can you confirm?

Comment: Exactly... i cannot manage the 2 different goal with the code i have inserted. The problem there is not reference between the script and the single contact form; so when i send a form, in GA there is 2 goal registered because the function wpc7mailsent refer to one event but send 2 events to GA